# html css tooltips on hover event can I make specific width?

Tags: html, css, hover, tooltip, inline

I have learned how to do basic tooltips, however, I need to specify a width for each one.
The code that I'm using is from w3 schools:

```
<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -5px;
  left: 0%;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>
```

The tooltip text is set to 500px.
I need to define each "span" a specific width:

```
<div class="tooltip">
this is the text to hover 
  <span class="tooltiptext">
this is the tooltip display
</span>
</div>
```

I have tried several ways to define the width (`<style="width: 800ps;"> text </style>)`
none of them have worked.

Comment: Which browsers?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by having inline style. Remove width from .tooltip and give width for every  like this:

```
<span class="tooltiptext" style="width: 100px;">
```

Comment: oh great i'll try that

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to [add an ID](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp#:%7E:text=The%20CSS%20id%20Selector,the%20id%20of%20the%20element.) to your tooltip divs.

The easiest way to describe an ID is that it is a unique name giving for an element.
For example instead of classes, that you can use on multiple elements. you can only use an id for 1 element.

in basic html and css it would look something like this:

html

```
<div class="test" id="DivOne">
    <p>ID ONE<p>
</div>

<div class="test" id="DivTwo">
    <p>ID TWO<p>
</div>
```

css

```
#DivOne{
    height: 200px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
}
#DivTwo{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: I was about to try that one, but that's an awful lot of code

Comment: This could be resume to a single rule for all elements, as well.
#DivOne,
#DivTwo{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}

Answer (score 0):

**Hi @anothen,**

In order for the browser to take into consideration your inline style, please remove the **width property rule** from your *.tooltiptext CSS class* and that will do the job. Don't forget to add the **inline style width** to the span as in the example below.

Last but not least, for the CSS span rules, you don't really need the *.tooltip .tooltiptext* syntax, you can leave it only with the **.tooltiptext** since this is merely affecting this element only.

I certainly hope this helps, pal!

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 0 auto;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -5px;
  left: 0%;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">
This is the text to hover 
<span class="tooltiptext" style="width:300px">
This is the tooltip display
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was working, I just forgot to disable cache.